# Delayed background task sometimes runs only when app returns to foreground

Tags: ios, delay, nstimer, background-process, geofencing

I am writing an iOS app for scanning barcodes at participating retail locations, where that location would donate to charity on the customer's behalf after the customer scans a QRcode printed on the receipt.

I would like to send a local notification to a user if they are in a participating location for 60 seconds or longer, reminding them to scan any receipts they might get from purchases they made there.

My issue is that I would like to delay a call for 60 seconds when a user enters a region - if after those 60 seconds they are still in that region fire off the local notification - however, sometimes that call to sendLocalNotification within stillInRegion doesn't fire until the app returns to the foreground. I believe this has to do with the thread sometimes ending before the delay is up, but I am not sure. I have tried about every approach I could find on stackoverflow and elsewhere (blocks, nstimers, etc.) but to no avail. Any ideas about how to better approach this problem?

```
- (void) sendLocalNotification:(NSString *)regionId {
NSLog(@"we entered %@ and we're currently in %@", regionId, self.currentRegionId);
if ([regionId isEqualToString:self.currentRegionId]) {// if we're still in the region, send a local notification
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil) return;
    NSDate *fireTime = [[NSDate date] addTimeInterval:2]; // adds 2 secs
    localNotif.fireDate = fireTime;
    localNotif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Did you just visit %@? If so, don't forget to scan your receipt!", regionId];
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber+1;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    [localNotif release];
}
}

- (void) stillInRegion:(CLRegion *)region {

NSLog(@"did enter region: %@", region.identifier);

[self performSelector:@selector(sendLocalNotification:) withObject:region.identifier afterDelay:60];
}

- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
if (self.didLaunchForRegionUpdate) {
    NSString *path = [DGGeofencingHelper applicationDocumentsDirectory];
    NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"notifications.dg"];
    NSMutableArray *updates = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];

    if (!updates) {
        updates = [NSMutableArray array];
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *update = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    [update setObject:region.identifier forKey:@"fid"];
    [update setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]] forKey:@"timestamp"];
    [update setObject:@"enter" forKey:@"status"];

    [updates addObject:update];

    [updates writeToFile:finalPath atomically:YES];
} else {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [dict setObject:@"enter" forKey:@"status"];
    [dict setObject:region.identifier forKey:@"fid"];
    NSString *jsStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DGGeofencing.regionMonitorUpdate(%@);", [dict JSONString]];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsStatement];
}
self.currentRegionId = region.identifier;
self.cRegionEnterTime =[NSDate date];
[self stillInRegion:region];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the locationManager:didEnterRegion being called in foreground and then your application goes to background?
I'm not very clear about when you are calling those methods, but you could try creating a background task as follows:

1. Add a property of type NSUInteger called, for example, bgTaskIdentifier, to store your background task identifier.
2. Before your call to [self stillInRegion:region]; add the following code:

   bgTaskIdentifier = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{}];
3. It should call your stillInRegion method, and continues even if you go to the background, so the delay should continue counting on!. Finally, you should end your background task. To do this, add the following line at the end of your sendLocalNotification method, after the if block:

   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTaskIdentifier];

Just let us know if that was helpful! and excuse me for my poor english!

Have a good day!

Comment: Thank you for your idea, I would actually need the didEnterRegion to handle calls either while app is in background or foreground. A use case would be user has phone in pocket, shops at retailer, app in background sends notification to user.

Comment: Nice! Just remember that iOS only allows 10 minutes of background execution!! i hope it changes with iOS 7!

Comment: So, can I create a background task to handle the delay while already in the background? Such as within the didEnterRegion method that might be called with app in background?

Comment: Theoretically you could, but i don't know if Apple likes that! you can read [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) link to have more information!

Comment: thank you again for your help. It seems that this could be a viable solution. Looking at the link you shared, I found this: "To request background execution time, call the beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: method of the UIApplication class. If your app moves to the background while the task is in progress, or if your app was already in the background, this method delays the suspension of your app." I have location background permissions already, and only need to delay a task by 60 seconds. I'll post an update later with my findings. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

inside my didEnterRegion method I used to following code to achieve the desired result:

```
 UIApplication*   app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    bgTaskIdentifier = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTaskIdentifier];
        bgTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        NSTimer* t = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:180 target:self  selector:@selector(stillInRegion:) userInfo:region.identifier repeats:NO];

        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:t forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
    });
```

Pretty close to what @lucaslt89 had but a slight variation on it.